# Different pandas DataFrame logical operation result when the changing the order

Tags: python, pandas

My code is like:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, True])
b = pd.DataFrame([True, np.nan])
c = a|b
print(c)
```

I don't know the result of logical operation result when one element is np.nan, but I expect them to be the same whatever the oder. But I got the result like this:

```
       0
0  False
1   True
```

Why? Is this about short circuiting in pandas? I searched the doc of pandas but did not find answer.

My pandas version is 1.1.3

Answer (score 2):

This is behaviour that is tied to `np.nan`, not pandas. Take the following examples:

```py
print(True or np.nan)
print(np.nan or True)
```

Output:

```py
True
nan
```

When performing the operation, dtype ends up mattering and the way that `np.nan` functions within the numpy library is what leads to this strange behaviour.

To get around this quirk, you can fill NaN values with `False` for example or some other token value which evaluates to `False` (using `pandas.DataFrame.fillna()`).

Comment: In pandas np.nan or True results in False, not nan. Is there a auto dtype transform in pandas? I thought pandas would keep it as nan.  But the result is False, which is confusing.

Comment: Yes it is casting the whole DataFrame to `bool` dtype for logical comparisons, and `np.nan` evaluates to `False` in this case.

Comment: This is really weird. nan evaluates to True when I use .astype(bool) method.